# PHP Return HTML (Laravel / Lumen Framework)

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a helper function with the following

**Note** I am using the following to parse content

https://github.com/erusev/parsedown

```
function display_docs_page($name){

    // Get Docs URL
    $docs_url = config('docs.docs_url');

    // Get File URL
    $file_url = $docs_url.'/'.$name.'.md';

    // Check If File Exists
    if (file_exists($file_url)) {

        // get raw file data
        $raw_file_data = file_get_contents($file_url);

        // convert data to html
        $parsedown = new Parsedown();

        return $parsedown->text($raw_file_data);

    } else {

        // 404
        return 'not_found';

    }

}
```

However when I run my function

```
return view('greeting', [
     'contents' => display_docs_page(config('general.homepage')),
]);
```

and try to echo out the variable so in blade

```
{{ $contents }}
```

I just just RAW html code. So its displaying the html data but its just raw code the browser isn't interpreting it.

[image: rawhtml]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Lumen / Laravel 5 you should use `{!! !!}` to output variable without escaping:

```blade
{!! $contents !!}
```

Read more: http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0 (Blade Tag Changes section)

Answer (score 0):

Its because by default laravel escaped everything in `{{ }}`, you must use `{!! $contents !!}` instead of `{{ $contents }}`